# Spacing problem with customized chapter style

Tags: titles, chapters, titlesec

I customized the chapter style like (`book` class):

[image]

More space between the Chapter title (`1 row`) and the Lines

[image]

Less space between the Chapter title (`2 or more rows`) and the Lines

How to solve this problem?

**Code:**

```
\usepackage{titlesec,microtype}

\newcommand{\thicktitlerule}{\titlerule[0.5 ex]}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
 { \vspace{ -1 em } \large } %\normalsize
 {\flushright \sffamily {\chaptNum\thechapter \vspace{1 ex}} \\\thicktitlerule}
 {-24 pt}
 {\titlerule\vspace{1 ex} \flushright \huge \bfseries}  
 [\vspace{1ex}] %\vspace{.2 em} \titlerule \vspace{0.5 em}

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
 {\vspace{ -1 em } \bfseries \normalsize}
 {\makebox[\textwidth]{\thicktitlerule}}
 {-2 pt}
 {\titlerule\vspace{1 ex}\flushright \huge}  
 [\vspace{1ex}]
```

Comment: I get the thin rule above the thick one. What's `\chaptNum`? You should use `\raggedleft`, not `\flushright`.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you want.

```
\newcommand{\thicktitlerule}{\titlerule[0.5 ex]}

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
{\bfseries\Large}
{}
{0ex}
{\thicktitlerule
\vspace{1pt}%
\titlerule
\vspace{2ex}%
\filleft\huge}
[\vspace{2ex}%
]

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\bfseries\Large}
{\filleft\Huge\sffamily\thechapter }
{1ex}
{\thicktitlerule
\vspace{1pt}
\titlerule
\vspace{2ex}%
\filleft\huge}
[\vspace{2ex}%
]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

To adjust the spacing further, put

```
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{3cm}
\titlespacing{name=\chapter,numberless}{0pt}{22pt}{3cm}
```

in the preamble and adjust to your liking.

Code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec,microtype,showframe}

\newcommand{\thicktitlerule}{\titlerule[0.5 ex]}

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
{\bfseries\Large}
{}
{0ex}
{\thicktitlerule
\vspace{1pt}%
\titlerule
\vspace{2ex}%
\filleft\huge}
[\vspace{2ex}%
]

\titlespacing{name=\chapter,numberless}{0pt}{22pt}{3cm}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\bfseries\Large}
{\filleft\Huge\sffamily\thechapter }
{1ex}
{\thicktitlerule
\vspace{1pt}
\titlerule
\vspace{2ex}%
\filleft\huge}
[\vspace{2ex}%
]
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{3cm}
\begin{document}
  \chapter{Introduction}
  \chapter{Particles interaction with multiphase fluid and the applications}
  \chapter*{Introduction}
  \chapter*{Particles interaction with multiphase fluid and the applications}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, the un-numbered chapter style is for `Contents` and `Nomenclature` etc, but the space above the lines is not the same as the chpaters.

Comment: @KOF I have added two lines. Those lines should do it.

Comment: Still not working :(, could you please give a MWE?

Comment: @KOF   Added to the answer. :)